# How to solve 'Input must be a vector, not an environment' when crawling website with R

Tags: r, rvest

I am crawling a website to R but error pops up: ! Input must be a vector, not an environment.

I attempt to crawl a website by doing

` simple <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kargil_War")

a <- simple %>%
html_nodes("p") %>%
html_text() `

The code works at the beginning but error pops up later:
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Input must be a vector, not an environment.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

How can I solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Your code works on my end; both lines of code results in a character vector (`a`), comprised of several lines of text. Have you recently updated R, RStudio, or any relevant packages (e.g., `rvest`, `dplyr`)? What do you get when you run `class(simple)`?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error when using version 1.5.0 of the `stringr` package. Reverting to `stringr` version 1.4.0 fixed your example for me.

```
require(devtools)
install_version("stringr", version = "1.4.0" )
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, updating the `vctrs`  worked for me.

```r
install.packages("vctrs")
```